# linked node list (how header is set only in the first while loop run but does not change thereafter)

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

The code at the bottom is to return a linked node list, which represents the sum of two input linked node lists.

My question is how

```
result = ListNode(0)
temp = result
```

(above the while loop)

```
temp.next = ListNode(out) 
temp = temp.next
```

(inside the while loop)

works such that if your linked node inputs are l1 = {3,4,1} and l2 = {4,6,2}, then result.next = {7,0,4}.  (result would be {0,7,0,4}

I am confused howr the first run of    `temp.next = ListNode(out)  temp = temp.next`

changes `result.next` from `None` to {7} but subsequent runs of  `temp.next = ListNode(out)  temp = temp.next` does not `change result.next`

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

    class Solution(object):
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
    """
    :type l1: ListNode
    :type l2: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    result = ListNode(0)     
    temp = result

    carry = 0

    while l1 or l2 or carry:            
        val1  = (l1.val if l1 else 0)
        val2  = (l2.val if l2 else 0)
        carry, out = divmod(val1+val2 + carry, 10)    

        temp.next = ListNode(out)    
        temp = temp.next 

        l1 = (l1.next if l1 else None)
        l2 = (l2.next if l2 else None)

    return result.next
```

Comment: because `temp` is getting re-assigned, it no longer refers to the same object as `result`, if that's what you are asking...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  So, the first time `temp.next = ListNode(out)` is run, assigning `ListNode(out)` to `temp.next` also resulted in  assigning `ListNode(out)` to `result.next` because `temp` and `result` were pointing to the same data and so changing one results in the same change in the other?

Comment: `temp is result` on the first iteration. However, on every other iteration `temp is not result` because it gets continually re-assigned. It's not "also" happening, they are two ways of saying the same thing. Think of it this way, there is an object with two different name tags on it, `temp` and `result`. All assignment does in Python is add, remove, or re-arrange name-tags on objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So, in the first run of `temp.next = ListNode(out)`, because `temp` and `result` are the name tags that refer to the same object (the object is `ListNode(out)` ), assigning `ListNode(out)` to `temp.next` also assigns `ListNode(out)` to `result.next`.  Would this be a fair way to describe it?

Comment: Yes, during the first iteration because `result = temp`, result.next = temp.next = ListNode(out) at line `temp.next = ListNode(out)`. Then, on the very next line (`temp = temp.next`), result no longer = temp because now temp = temp.next = ListNode(out), and so result.next is never updated again.